# Create custom media player like Youtube in Android

Tags: android, media-player

I have to create media player like youtube player.Actually if i use VideoView for play video and MediaController for controll video(MediaController onlyu provides play,pause,next,pre and seek options).But in my player i have to add one more option i.e bandwidth(I would have three bandwidth and on clicking on bandwidth video will play).So please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I know, MediaController doesn't give many opportunities to be customized. So, you have two options depending on your UI requirements and the effort you are willing to do.

1. The hard way: You can just get rid of Android MediaController and
   implement your own media controller, since you are not bound to use
   it. MediaPlayer (through VideoView) provides you the needed
   functions to build it: pause(), play(), resume() methods and event
   listeners like onPrepared, onStopped, etc. To display the progress
   bar you can use SeekBar, but you will have to code the interaction
   with MediaPlayer (this is, the progress bar will not move alone).
2. The easy way: you can find another place to put your bandwith
   button, for instance, on the top of the screen. You might even place
   your button over MediaController.

Comment: Your 1st way will work for my requirement.I have downloaded mediaController code form http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/MediaController.java But there is error here.So can you provide me complete MediaController Code and i'll edit it.

Comment: I don't recommend you to build your media controller from Android's media controller, although you can take it as a guide. I recommend you to build a layout with play, pause buttons and a seek bar and code your own interaction. It's not very difficult, play/pause buttons are trivial, the most difficult thing is the SeekBar, but don't worry, you can create an infinite loop with a Handler (look at mHandler from Android's media controller) and take care when user moves SeekBar in order to move video to some time.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a layout properly combining the GUI elements you need. VideoView can be used with other GUI elements like buttons and can be nested within layouts like RelativeLayout and LinearLayout.

So, if you want your bandwidth button adjacent to VideoView, you may use LinearLayout, if you want your bandwith button over the video surface, like MediaController, you may use RelativeLayout, managing properly the layers.

Comment: Thanks for replay @Fran J Martínez I want to add bandwidth button in MediaContrller(this will be spinner)

Answer (score -1):

have a look at SurfaceView, that will give you an idea on not bounding your logic with player.